# Только бы не пики!

Tags: синтаксис, сослагательное-наклонение

Ситуация: люди играют в карты и один из игроков опасается, что к нему придет карта пик. Это его реплика: **Только бы не пики**!

Можно утверждать, что здесь скрывается сослагательное наклонение (с опущенным глаголом на *-л*?) (=quasi *только бы не выпали пики*!) Или я ошибаюсь?

Спасибо!

Comment: @shampar: спасибо за исправление!!! : ) я автоматически из своего языка как "пика" перевела...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, Вы правы, на сослагательное наклонение указывает частица БЫ.